# Can somone explain the layer target icon?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

In the Illustrator layer pallete, somtimes the layer target icon is filled in, and somtimes not.

[image: Layer target icons]

Can somone explain to me what the difference is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Illustrator help pages

> The target icon indicates whether an item in the layer hierarchy has any appearance attributes and whether it is targeted

The filled in icon means the layer has appearance attributes beyond a single fill and a single stroke.

You can read more here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/appearance-attributes.html